# Name of a Christmas movie, probably foreign, involving a giant

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's a live action film based around two kids if I remember correctly, and one of them is slapped by a teacher in the very beginning. All I can recall after that is an attractive looking Mrs. Claus type character taken hostage by a giant in a cabin in the woods. I think the children try to save her. May or may not have had musical elements. Very odd film that always stuck with me, very well could have been Scandinavian.

Comment: any idea how old it is?

Comment: Sorry, that would be important wouldn't it? Most likely the 80's, probably early 80's. I saw it so young though, and I'm 29 now so it's difficult for me to recall when I actually first saw it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it! I was being too specific with my details when googling. It's called *J'ai rencontré le Père Noël*, a French movie from 1984. The dubbed American version is called either *Here Comes Santa Claus* or *I Believe in Santa Claus*. And it wasn't a giant, it was an ogre!